# Namespace from NuGet package reference canot be found in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use the [Aftership](https://github.com/AfterShip/aftership-net) SDK in ASP.Net 5 Beta 3 but even though I've added it as a dependency I still get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynCompilationException:
  ~/myproject/Controllers/PackagesController.cs(5,7): 
      error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Aftership' could not be
      found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

All of the related SO questions say to remove the CoreCLR framework reference from the `packages.json` file, but I've already done that:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "exclude": "wwwroot/**/*.*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS":"1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Aftership": "4.0.8"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
        "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": { }
    }
}
```

My controller code is standard:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Mirror.Models;
using Aftership;
using System.Linq;

namespace Mirror.Controllers
{
    public class PackagesController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {        
            return View(GetPackages());
        }

        private List<Package> GetPackages()
        {
            var packages = new List<Package>();

            var conn = new ConnectionAPI("...");
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

After running `kpm restore` I can find the library located in my packages directory under: `~/.k/packages/Aftership/4.0.8/lib/net40/Aftership-API.exe`

Could the issue be due to the Aftership library providing an exe rather than an appropriately named `Aftership.dll`? I have tried to rename the file, but no success...

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that it's built for .Net 4.0. Maybe I'll have to compile from source (luckily it's up on Github).

Comment: Yes it should be a DLL... why is the library an EXE?

Comment: It looks like they have a Main function that runs some makeshift tests (in addition to their NUnit tests) and they probably packaged the whole thing into one project. It doesn't look like their developer was well-versed in .Net (the SDK is a thin wrapper around their HTTP APIs) but I guess I appreciate the thought. I'll just build a new copy and use that.

Comment: Feel free to log a bug in https://github.com/aspnet/DNX/issues to see if support for referencing EXE's could be added. It's kind of a weird scenario because EXEs are meant to, umm... execute, whereas DLLs are meant to ummm, be dynamic libraries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just compiling it myself into a DLL (which meant I could target .Net 4.5 too) and building a private NuGet package for it. Thank goodness for Open Source Software!

Thanks @Elion for confirming that DLLs are the only supported reference.